# What are the mandatory screenshot for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I cant' really find on Apple's documentation something that tells me what are the **mandatory** screens to upload.

With so many devices, resolutions, etc... I found everything confusing

Can you help?

Comment: Here you can find more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Answer (score 7):

From now (April 2019) you should add 6.5 inch (iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR):

> 1242 x 2688 pixels (portrait)
>
> 2688 x 1242 pixels (landscape)
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone

UPDATE (2021):
On iPhone you should also add 5.5 inch (iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus):

> 1242 x 2208 pixels (portrait)
>
> 2208 x 1242 pixels (landscape)
>
> Required if app runs on iPhone

and (if runs on iPad) - 12.9 inch (iPad Pro (3rd generation)):

> 2048 x 2732 pixels (portrait)
>
> 2732 x 2048 pixels (landscape)

also.

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Answer (score 2):

As of Feb 2020, for an iPhone app you need 2 sets:

- 6.5 inch (iPhone 11 etc)
- 5.5 inch (iPhone 8 etc)

The [guideline](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925) gives more details eg. if you also support iPad.

Interestingly, I also discovered app reviewers can approve [even if you don't have 5.5 inch screenshot](https://samwize.com/2020/02/08/bet-you-didnt-know-you-dont-need-5-5-screenshots-for-app-store/).

Answer (score 1):

From the link what tonik12 linked:

> 5.5-Inch Retina Display Screenshots. Add up to four screenshots. Smaller iPhone devices can use this set of screenshots.

So minimum seems to be one screenshot with 5.5 inch

Answer (score 1):

If your app is the same across device sizes and localizations, you can use the highest resolution screenshot for each device type; this set will scale appropriately for other device sizes when viewed on the App Store in each localization available in iTunes Connect. For example, if your app supports only the iPhone, you can provide 5.5-inch display screenshots and you do not need separate screenshots for the 4.7-inch, 4.0-inch and 3.5-inch displays. If your app supports iPad, a 12.9-Inch Display screenshot is required.

[image]

if you want more information
[please see this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2)